# Sonarqube coverage configuration for React and Jest

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, jestjs, sonarjs

I have problem with configuration sonarqube to work properly with React + Jest.

My configuration:

`my_moudle.sonar.projectBaseDir=front_app`
`my_module.sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx`

`my_module.sonar.tests=src`

`my_module.sonar.test.inclusions=**/__tests__/**` `my_module.sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info`

Currently I point to the src folder as tests folder because I have set of tests for each component in **tests** folder at the same project folder. 
Thanks to SonarJS I have proper coverege for my project, but I don't know why I can't see amount of unit tests in coverage measures metrics.
Any checked configuration will be appreciate.

Thanks,
Barb

Comment: my_moudle is misspelled

Answer (score 23):

SonarJS is not responsible for Unit test reports, ([Relevant FAQ entry](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/blob/master/docs/DOC.md#q-how-to-import-results-of-tests-execution-into-sonarqubesonarcloud))
It is the responsibility of SonarQube to import the Unit test report.

I have managed to do it with the following setup.

First we need to convert the jest results into [sonar consumable format](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data). For this, I used the following npm module: [jest-sonar-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-sonar-reporter).

Snippet of my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
   ...
    "jest": "^21.1.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    ...
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "sonar56x": true,
    "reportPath": "testResults",
    "reportFile": "sonar-report.xml",
    "indent": 4
  }
```

You can will now need to tell jest to use this module as a processor and tell sonar scanner to use the file produced by this module. The instructions are in the official documentation.

If you are using create-react-app/react-scripts though, you may need a few additional steps, as all configuration is not exposed by them.

You will need to modify your entry for test in `scripts` block in package.json to:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor ./node_modules/jest-sonar-reporter/index.js
```

Comment: This really works, thanks!

My setup is like the following:

script line in package.json:

`"test:ci": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --reporters=default --coverage --testResultsProcessor ./node_modules/jest-sonar-reporter/index.js",`

jestSonar configuration in package.json

   `"jestSonar": {
       "reportPath": ".",
       "reportFile": "sonar-report.xml",
       "indent": 4
     },`


sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=sonar-report.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to configure sonar-scan to include my tests as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466369/sonarqube-test-report-report-refers-to-a-file-which-is-not-configured-as-a-test